# Airflow Slack failed to send Message

Tags: airflow

I am trying to achieve Airflow integration with Slack, 
have received the webhook URL, and created the connection as below. Why is it showing google.com ??

Why is it using the default http_conn_id and connecting to google ??

But got an error as below

ERROR - Error in sending a message to Slack channel #airflow-alerts
            by Airflow: 404:Not Found

```
{base_hook.py:83} INFO - Using connection to: id: http_default. Host: https://www.google.com/, Port: None, Schema: None, Login: None, Password: None, extra: {}
{logging_mixin.py:95} INFO - [2020-05-29 12:43:21,374] {http_hook.py:128} INFO - Sending 'POST' to url: https://www.google.com//T00A6ASFHD8S/G1FDF4K/a3zfKsadfsrScxgadfsdafOIgIvgW

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://www.google.com//T00A6ASFHD8S/G1FDF4K/a3zfKsadfsrScxgadfsdafOIgIvgW
```

[image]

But I got the below error, unable to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out after long struggle ...

There was a bug in SlackWebhookOperator in Airflow≤1.10.3 (Bug Jira Issue). This was fixed in 1.10.4 with this PR (fix commit).

Answer (score 2):

Your connection is not setup correctly, you need to select `HTTP` as the `Conn Type`, leave the `Extra` field blank and put the webhook token (format is `/STRING/STRING/STRING`) in the `Password` field. Then you can use the `SlackWebhookOperator` [operator](https://medium.com/datareply/integrating-slack-alerts-in-airflow-c9dcd155105) which allows you to set the channel and username.

Comment: How do I get the username and channel to pass to the SlackOperator

Comment: Pass them as parameters (`username='Airflow', channel='#airflow_alerts'`) in the SlackWebhookOperator: https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/slack_webhook_operator.html

Comment: I cannot hard code in the slackoperator parameters coz i have multiple slack channels , depending on applications ... Issue here why is it going to default http_conn_id that is google.com

Comment: Are you running Airflow version <= 1.10.3? There's a bug in these versions that causes the behaviour you describe.

Comment: The version is 1.10.3, but I see other teams also using the same version and he was able to get alerts .. I guess something I am missing wr.t connection

Comment: Simplest solution is to upgrade. Is this an option for your setup?

Comment: An upgrade option is separate task which will take time

Comment: I had to setup my connection like that. Type = HTTP, Host = http s://hooks.slack.com/services (without space), Password = /STRING/STRING/STRING (my token). It then worked. Thanks